# Declare global variable that is accessed by all classes C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, class, global-variables

We are working on a project in C++. I'm trying to create header and source file for every class, by simply creating a class in Eclipse.

What I'm trying to achieve not is to declare a global variable that is accessible from all the classes.

For example,

**Im_Position.cpp**

```
#include "Im_Position.h"

void Im_Position::Im_GetPosition (const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    vehicle_position.x_pose = msg->pose.pose.position.x;
    vehicle_position.y_pose = msg->pose.pose.position.y;

    vehicle_position.x_orient = msg->pose.pose.orientation.x;
    vehicle_position.y_orient = msg->pose.pose.orientation.y;
    vehicle_position.z_orient = msg->pose.pose.orientation.z;
    vehicle_position.w_orient = msg->pose.pose.orientation.w;
}
```

**Im_Position.h**

```
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"

class Im_Position {
    public:
        void Im_GetPosition(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg);
};
```

I'm getting an error in Im_Position.cpp that says the vehicle_position is not declared in this scope. I dont know if its caused by my coding style or the Eclipse's linking problems. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS environment.

**Im_RobotKontrol.cpp**

```
#include "Im_Position.h"

typedef struct{
double x_pose;
double y_pose;
double x_orient;
double y_orient;
double z_orient;
double w_orient;
} position_type;

extern position_type vehicle_position;

int main()
{
  ...
}
```

It is actually declared in another source file that can be seen above, because I want it to be used in all the classes.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: global variables are bad idea. Try to redesign to avoid their use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined `vehicle_position` anywhere. Your

```
extern position_type vehicle_position;
```

only says that a `position_type vehicle_position` exists somewhere, and only to code in **Im_Robotcontrol.c**. What you need to do is to put the `extern` declaration in a header-file accessible to the files that needs to reach this variable, and then you need to define it in *one* c-file. For example as

```
position_type vehicle_position;
```

in your Im_Robotcontrol.c.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `vehicle_position` is declare in  Im_RobotKontrol.cpp and there is no linking between Im_Position.cpp and Im_RobotKontrol.cpp.

And by the way you can use object for doing this all rather than extern.